# Can I make NullReferenceException more clear?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to know the name of the variable that caused a NullReferenceException to be thrown, only from looking at the error (problems window).

Comment: VS should indicate where the exception got fired, at least provide us with some codes

Comment: The short answer is No. The longer answer requires a [mcve].

Comment: You're assuming there's a variable name. Given `a.Foo().bar`, it's entirely possible that `a` is non-null but `a.Foo()` returns null. What sort of thing are you looking for in cases like that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

Unlike exceptions thrown by programmers' code, such as `ArgumentNullException` or `InvalidOperationException`, `NullReferenceException` is thrown by the runtime itself. It happens at a level where carrying variable names is impractical. Your error-checking code guards "payload" code by ensuring the preconditions are met. That is how you anticipate potential errors programmers using your code could make:

```
void DoSomething(string arg1, string arg2) {
    if (arg1 == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(arg1));
    if (arg2 == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(arg2));
    ...
}
```

Unlike your code, runtime cannot enumerate all preconditions without becoming impractical. The number of things that could cause `NullReferenceException` is pretty high even in a relatively straightforward expression:

```
retObj.Result.List = myObj.Process().FirstOrDefault().ToList();
```

C# would need to prepare an error message for each of the following:

- `retObj`
- `retObj.Result`
- `myObj`
- `myObj.Process()`
- `myObj.Process().FirstOrDefault()`

That is five strings just for a single line of code!

Moreover, C# would need to deal with this differently in release code to avoid giving away things about your code that hackers could potentially exploit. An error message with `NullReferenceException` that details the expression that caused the error could tell hackers that you are using a particular API or library, for which they may have a ready exploit.

Since `NullReferenceException` is ultimately an error that indicates a programming error, you should add your own checks to ensure that your code never throws it, no matter what arguments are passed into it. Null-checking parameters and ensuring that the internal state is consistent goes long way not only toward eliminating `NullReferenceException`s, but also making your code much easier to understand by listing its pre-conditions explicitly.

**Note:** Visual Studio 2017 debugger could help you figure out the cause of the exception with [Null Reference Analysis](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/03/31/using-the-new-exception-helper-in-visual-studio-15-preview/) feature. It comes with restrictions, though: the code must be compiled for .NET version 4.6.2 or above, not target UWP or .NET Core, and have no JIT optimizations (thanks [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) for a great comment).

Comment: The new Null Reference Analysis feature is [mentioned here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/03/31/using-the-new-exception-helper-in-visual-studio-15-preview/)

Comment: Thanks @dasblinkenlight for the informative answer. I guess from now on I will make sure that my code never throws NullReferenceException.